Помощь с PrimeOS
Поставили с другом PrimeOS. При включении ноутбука вылезает меню GRUB с выбором OC, но там нет винды. Пробовали через биос, не получилось. Для PrimeOS делали отдельный раздел на диске.

Пересоздать настройки grub с включенным os-prober?
